# Pythonic way of looping through a binary file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary file with a small header, then 100 blocks of binary data in an identical format. I *can* read it like this:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    read_header(f)
    while 1:
        data = f.read(size)
        if len(data) != size:
            break
        do_stuff(data)
```

`while 1`/`break` seems weird for something that should be simple. Is there a way to write this as a `for` loop (without just hiding the `while` loop in a pointless extra class, or reading the entire file at once)?

Something like:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    read_header(f)
    for data in f.split(size):
        do_stuff(data)
```

Comment: `for chunk in iter(partial(openfileobject.read, 1024), ''):`, replace the chunk size with whatever you need.